# JSON Decoding into array

Tags: php

Can someone help me with json decoding

```
<?php

 //build query
$query = 
  "SELECT 
  userid, 
  username, 
  password, 
  email 
  FROM Users ORDER BY userid";

$results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$arRows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  array_push($arRows, $row);
}

$results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
echo json_encode($arRows);
$encode = json_encode($arRows);

?>
```

This is the array which is encoded, now I want it decoded.

Answer (score 1):

add

`$decode = json_decode($encode, true);`

and `$decode` will be an array. :)

Comment: Sorry for the earlier mistakes :) the above is the correct form!

Comment: A detail, but shouldn't it be `json_decode($encode, true);`? (and not `$arRows`)

Comment: @caCtus :)) so one more mistake... sorry I am really tired :( Tx for the catch btw :D